# Are the Scammer Aliens from Bender's Big Score references to Singularity Sky?

Tags: futurama, charles-stross

I recently read Charles Stross' *Singularity Sky* (2003). Within, there are a group of creatures known as the Critics, who resemble large naked mole rats. Likewise, in the Futurama film *Bender's Big Score* (2007), the scammer aliens resemble large naked mole rats.

While the Critics provide high-level commentary and analysis for the Festival by visiting the affected planets, the scammer aliens gather a massive amount of intimate details about their victims.

Are their similarities coincidental, or was it meant as a (very) subtle reference to Stross' novel?

Comment: I just assumed they were from Planet-419

Answer (score 3):

## It's never mentioned.

While possible, I've found no references to Singularity Sky in the [DVD commentary](https://theinfosphere.org/Commentary:Bender%27s_Big_Score), [wiki page](https://theinfosphere.org/Miscellany_of_Bender%27s_Big_Score), or web searches. I would guess that the similarities are coincidental.